# Use class from specific other assembly if that assembly is loaded, performantly and without any boilerplate code

Tags: .net, architecture

*I will describe the situation in abstract terms, as the actual subject of the code is irrelevant for the time being. This question is merely about the architecture/code organisation in the project.*

---

I am creating a set of reusable C# libraries.

Assembly *A* offers a set of related features.
A few of these features require an implementation of `ISomething`.
The implementation of `ISomething` to use is determined in a static configuration class provided by *A*, `Config.Something`.

Assembly *B* contains an implementation of `ISomething`, namely `DefaultSomething`.

**I am looking for a way to**

1. let users use assemblies *A* and *B* by simply referencing them and accessing types from *A*. In this situation, `Config.Something` should automatically be set to/assumed to be `DefaultSomething`.
2. let users use assembly *A* and supply their own implementation of `ISomething`. In this situation, assembly *B* should not be required and users should be able to assign a custom object to `Config.Something`.
3. let users use only those features from *A* that do not require `ISomething`s, so neither *B* nor an assignment to `Config.Something` are required.

While cases (2) and (3) are trivial, I am not sure how to best design the library to support case (1).
I have examined various ways to solve this, but each of them has some drawbacks:

- Users could be asked to perform the assignment `Config.Something` = `new DefaultSomething()` themselves in case (1). However, I do not want to require this sort of boilerplate code. Case (1) should be really "plug-and-play", or rather, reference-assemblies and write custom code using *A*.
- In case (1), the code in *A* could search for class `DefaultSomething` by means of reflection the first time an `ISomething` is required. However, especially when many assemblies are loaded, this seems quite wasteful and slow. I might be able to identify *B* relatively quickly by marking it with a custom attribute declared in *A* that is not publicly visible, but giving *B* access to *A*'s internals. This sounds somewhat hacky, though.
- *B* registers itself with *A* as soon as *B* is loaded. This would be my preferred solution, but I don't think there is any way to automatically run any code from an assembly once that assembly has been loaded.

**Is there any good way to do this?**

Answer (score 1):

Without specific examples there will be a lot of ways to achieve that.

Generally speaking, looks like you need a [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) Container (like Unity/[Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) if you are using .NET) and/or a plugin system (handmade, or MEF if you are using .NET).

Comment: Ok, I suppose those frameworks more or less come down to what I described in the first two solutions, i.e. boilerplate setup code or some more or less complete scan of what is loaded by means of reflection. I suppose I'll stick with "handmade" in this case, because using a full-fledged plugin system for a single assignment sounds like a bit of overkill.

Comment: I second the MEF recommendation. it is very simple to use and bootstrap and works very reliably for this scenario. Also to mention it is used inside visual studio to load editor extensions (I think it was created originally for that purpose)

Comment: @Bishoy: As I wrote, I think using a plugin framework like MEF for a single assignment is some overkill, and the plugin framework probably does the same reflection under the hood that I'd be doing otherwise, but I'm indeed looking forward to using MEF in other contexts.